# AppleScript / Javascript : remove columns in Safari

Tags: applescript, safari, javascript

Is there a way to remove all instance of a class in safari using AppleScript/Javascript ?

For e.g I would like to remove each instance of :

```
`<td class="sortable cardTypeDisplayName">

                                    Visa

                            </td>`
```

I suppose that might have something to do with this but I'm lost in the script as I don't have experience with JS

```
tell application "Safari"
    set RemoveWhatIDontWant to do JavaScript "javascript:Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('sortable cardTypeDisplayName'))
.forEach(function(v){v.removeAttribute('sortable cardTypeDisplayName');});" in document 1
end tell
```

UPDATE :

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.querySelectorAll("[class=\"sortable cardTypeDisplayName\"]")
        .forEach(el => el.remove());" in tab 1 of window 1
end tell
```

Result :

> Syntax Error Expected end of line but found “[”.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662550/how-to-remove-all-instances-of-a-class-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: @Daniil Importing jQuery just to perform a single operation is overkill, and I don't see any of the the linked solutions resolving the problem here even if jQuery is imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `.removeAttribute(attrName)` takes an attribute name, **not** value.
  The attribute name is 'class', the value is 'sortable cardTypeDisplayName'.
- However, that's not going to fix the problem either. Removing the attribute from the element doesn't remove the element entirely, it just removes the attribute, such that your example becomes `<td>Visa</td>` — i.e. the column still exists.

To remove all elements with a class attribute exactly matching 'sortable cardTypeDisplayName', you can use the following JavaScript.

```
document.querySelectorAll("[class=\"sortable cardTypeDisplayName\"]")
        .forEach(el => el.remove());
```

This problem is with your JavaScript, not AppleScript. Debug your JavaScript in the web browser developer tools first before moving to AppleScript.

To run this JavaScript with AppleScript, keep in mind the quotes that need escaping. Look at the syntax highlighting to see how the quotes in the JavaScript are being parsed as quotes for AppleScript to use on the string itself, rather than given to JavaScript. These quotes need escaping.

```
tell application "Safari" to ¬
  do JavaScript "document.querySelectorAll(\"[class=\\\"module question-stats\\\"]\").forEach(el => el.remove());" ¬
    in current tab of window 1
```

```
tell application "Safari" to ¬
  do JavaScript "document.querySelectorAll('[class=\"module question-stats\"]').forEach(el => el.remove());" ¬
    in current tab of window 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that's work perfectly within Safari console. I feel stupid for asking, but how can I integrate this with AppleScript, I always get an error when trying to compile (updating my post with my error)

Comment: @Kevin Watch the quotes, they need escaping — see edit

Comment: @grg, I'm no JavaScript expert... far from it; however, I'll typically use single-quotes where I can so I do not have to escape the double-quotes... can that be applied here?

Comment: @user Indeed you can, thanks I've added a version with single quotes, it's still not possible to do away with *all* the escaping though!